# Kotlin gradle build Unresolved reference to kotlin-stdlib functions

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I have the following `build.gradle` file for my package

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.21"
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += "./"
}
```

On running `gradle compileKotlin` I get the following errors

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)                                                                                                                                                           
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/ConnectionHandler.kt: (26, 35): Too many arguments for public constructor String() defined in kotlin.String                                                                  
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/ConnectionHandler.kt: (26, 38): Unresolved reference: trim                                                                                                                   
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/ConnectionHandler.kt: (30, 29): Unresolved reference: isEmpty                                                                                                                
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/ConnectionHandler.kt: (40, 9): Unresolved reference: print                                                                                                                   
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/ConnectionHandler.kt: (41, 9): Unresolved reference: print                                                                                                                   
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/ConnectionHandler.kt: (45, 9): Unresolved reference: println                                                                                                                 
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpRequest.kt: (8, 19): Unresolved reference: HashMap                                                                                                                       
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpRequest.kt: (16, 38): Unresolved reference: split                                                                                                                        
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpResponse.kt: (22, 31): Unresolved reference: toByteArray                                                                                                                 
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpStatusCodes.kt: (3, 22): Unresolved reference: HashMap                                                                                                                   
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpStatusCodes.kt: (3, 45): Unresolved reference: hashMapOf                                                                                                                 
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpStatusCodes.kt: (5, 9): Unresolved reference: to                                                                                                                         
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpStatusCodes.kt: (6, 9): Unresolved reference: to                                                                                                                         
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpStatusCodes.kt: (7, 9): Unresolved reference: to                                                                                                                         
e: /home/ishan/code/kotlin-server/server/HttpStatusCodes.kt: (8, 9): Unresolved reference: to
```

When I use `kotlinc -include-runtime` command to compile this package, it compiles without any issues and I even have a working `.jar` file for it.

What am I missing here? If you want to inspect more, I've also created a [github issue](https://github.com/ishankhare07/kotlin-web-server/issues/1) for this with links to the related code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}
```

at the top-level, not inside the `buildscript`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.21"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += "./"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the dependency has to be put in the dependencies block outside buildscript. However, you also have to specify the version of the stdlib to use:

```
buildscript{
    ...
}
dependencies{
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```